# Variables in xpath expressions

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Is it not posssible to use xsl:variables in xpath expressions? I am sure that my variable has the correct value. Have tried it both as String and number. The first one works but the second one selects all contents nodes and not just the one with index 4.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/contents[4]/content" >
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/contents[$myVariable]/content" >
```

edit

```
    <xsl:variable name="dayOfWeekIndex">    
        <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'monday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(1)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'tuesday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(2)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'wednesday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(3)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'thursday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(4)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'friday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(5)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'saturday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(6)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'sunday'">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(7)" />
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: You may be interested to see an XPath *one-liner* that does what the 25 lines above do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="dayOfWeekIndex">    
    <xsl:choose>    
        <xsl:when test="lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'monday'">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(1)" />
        </xsl:when>
        ....
```

An `<xsl:variable>` with content but no `as` attribute will set the variable to a "temporary tree", not a number, so a predicate `[$dayOfweekIndex]` is treated as a boolean predicate rather than a restriction on the nodes' `position()`.  You need to add `as="xs:integer"` to the `xsl:variable` tag to force the variable to have the correct type.

Alternatively, use a `select` instead, with the `if` construct in XPath 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="dayOfWeekIndex" as="xs:integer" select="
    if (lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'monday') then 1 else
    if (lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'tuesday') then 2 else
    .....
    if (lower-case($dayOfWeek) = 'sunday') then 7 else
    0" />
```

Comment: Using `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of` inside the `xsl:variable` does not change the type of the `xsl:variable`, as long as it is set up as `<xsl:variable name="dayOfWeekIndex">..</xsl:variable>` with non-empty content it is a temporary tree (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#temporary-trees), so you need to use `as="xs:integer"` or you need to use the `select` attribute with an XPath expression returning an `xs:integer` to be able to use the variable in a positional predicate.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, I've edited the answer in light of your comment.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am not realy getting the difference between number and xs:integer but I will read about this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It matters how you set up the variable or parameter obviously e.g. with

```
<xsl:variable name="index" select="4"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/contents[$index]/content"/>
```

it should work (i.e. process the fourth `contents`), with

```
<xsl:variable name="index">4</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/contents[$index]/content"/>
```

it doesn't work as the predicate expression is not of type `xs:integer`, it is a non empty sequence of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**As others have noticed, specifying the type of a variable really matters in XSLT 2.0.**

**In addition to this, this transformation shows how to use an XPath one-liner to produce the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vWeekDays" as="xs:string+" select=
 "('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday')"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vdayOfWeek" select="'Friday'"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="index-of($vWeekDays, lower-case($vdayOfWeek))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

**When this transformation**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="para1" select="chapter/para"/>
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates select="$para1"/></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**runs on below XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter>
<para>This is para</para>
</chapter>
```

**get the output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<p>This is para</p>
```

Comment: @user874774: Without knowing your full code, we could not able to rectify your problem. If you want use this as reference.